# Can't load Font Awesome from subdirectory

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have the following file layout:

```
/website/index.html
/website/font-awesome/css
/website/font-awesome/fonts
/website/Subdirectory/page1.html
```

The page `/website/index.html` does not use Font Awesome at all; the files in `/website/Subdirectory/` do use it.

If I directly access `/website/Subdirectory/page1.html` the Font Awesome icons show as a box with UniCode number inside. If I visit `/website/index.html` first, then visiting any page in the Subdirectory will show the icons as expected.

On `page1.html` I have `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">`.

This is locally hosted; i.e. via `file://`

**Update**

```
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "FontAwesome" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): status=2147500037
source: file:///correct/path/to/website/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0
```

I'm using Firefox on a Mac. According to Finder the font version is 4.2.0.

On Chrome this problem does not exist. Looks like some kind of browser implementation issue. Work arounds appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue, due to "same origin" security policy, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=760436

The reason why the site works after loading the higher level page is that the font has been cached already.

Comment: hmm I thought "same origin policy" is all about cross sub domain issues. But from your question it seems to be in the same domain?

Comment: The cache thing got me. Ensure to empty the cache _before_ thinking that the cause is something really complex....

Answer (score 3):

Either ensure that the font file is in the same directory as the page that's trying to load it, or a subdirectory of this (not a sibling or ancestor directory); or else relax the security check by setting `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` to `false` in about:config.

Answer (score 0):

the issue for me was to set the environment variable as follow in my rails app.

config.action_controller.relative_url_root  = "/myrailsapp"

see  https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails